# factorization of the group SU(3)

Tags: lie-groups

My question is if there is a way to construct a factorization of SU(3) into products of the 3 subgroups copies of SU(2)  through the root system? [image]

Comment: No, $SU(2)$ is a simple Lie group.

Comment: ok thank you, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Rather, $SU(3)$ is a simple Lie group. A simple Lie group cannot be represented as a direct product of two Lie groups of positive dimension.